# How to render abc.php when user requested abc.html

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

How i can render .php files as .html using .htaccess.

Tried below code but still not working

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [NC]

<FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-html
</FilesMatch>

AddHandler php5-script .php .html
```